# when $\sqrt{y}$ and $\sqrt{x}$ are defined, is $\sqrt{y}$ = $\sqrt{x}$ a function?

Tags: functions

when $\sqrt{y}$ and $\sqrt{x}$ are defined, is $\sqrt{y}$ = $\sqrt{x}$ a function? for (x,y) in the reals. I think I'm thinking to hard about what the graph will look like

Comment: Hint: Square both sides and see what happens

Comment: $\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{x} \Rightarrow y=x$.

Comment: I believe your question betrays a (small) misunderstanding of what a function is. My answer (downvoted without comments) gives the background on this.

Answer (score 2):

Not so hard to find. The graph is the half-line $y=x, x\geq 0, y\geq 0$. [image]

Comment: I have never heard anyone call $y=x$ a half-line... interesting.

Comment: But you’ve heard people calling it a ray. That is the same.

Comment: This isn't a criticism. I just haven't heard the terminology before. Learn something new everyday.

Comment: No i did not take that as a criticism. I’m french speaker, and in french the name is “demi-droite” which mean in English half-line

Comment: You are plotting the solution of an equation, not answering the question whether $\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{x}$ would be a function.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{x}$ is not what you call a *function*, it is an *equation*.

The solution $y(x)$ to that equation over positive numbers $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ is a function, it is 
\begin{align*}
y : &&\mathbb{R}^+ &\mapsto \mathbb{R}\\
&&x &\rightarrow x
\end{align*}
also called the identity function, here resticted to positive numbers. You easily see that  it is such that $\sqrt{y(x)}=\sqrt{x}$ for all $x$ in its domain $\mathbb{R}^+$, so this *function* solves the *equation* $\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{x}$.

You often abbreviate it as $y(x)=x$ but this is a shortcut for the above (and a shortcut that doesn't mention on which interval it operates, which can be a problem sometimes).

The solution to $y=\sqrt{x}$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$ would have been
\begin{align*}
y : &&\mathbb{R}^+ &\mapsto \mathbb{R}\\
&&x &\rightarrow \sqrt{x}
\end{align*}
and the one to $\sqrt{y}=x$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$ would have been
\begin{align*}
y : &&\mathbb{R}^+ &\mapsto \mathbb{R}\\
&&x &\rightarrow x^2
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you explain downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Attempt:

1) $x,y \gt 0.$

We have $√y-√x=0:$

Recall: $y-x=(√y-√x)(√y+√x).$

Then:
$y-x=0$ $\iff$ $(√y-√x)=0$, since $√y+√x >0$.

2) $x=y=0$ , then trivially $√y=√x$, and $y=x$.

Hence for $x,y \ge 0$ we get the more familiar form of a function $y=x$.